# Workspaces in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

What are the different workspaces in Roslyn and the differences between them? I only know of `MSBuildWorkspace` and `AdhocWorkspace`. How does workspace affects Roslyn analysis? I have read that you need `DnxWorkspace` for MVC projects but I have not try them out yet.

Comment: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/

Comment: any idea on how each of this affects analysis on MVC projects? I have read that MVC projects need DnxWorkspace. Any idea on Dnxworkspace? thanks.

Comment: Yes. MVC Projects need DnxWorkspace for the analysis purpose.  It's hard to explain unless you say what you accomplished so far. You need to download a nuget package to start with. `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Dnx`. Please be clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not too sure about what you meant by "What im trying to achieve", but basically what im doing is a static code analyzer to detect security vulnerabilities in ASP.NET projects. It is running fine on WebForms type of project now but not MVC projects. Im using a lot of the symbol API in my code and hence get lots of null reference pointer when i analyse MVC projects. So what is the difference that made Dnxworkspace able to analyse MVC projects? thanks!

Comment: @KimKangIn: `DnxWorkspace` is for _.Net Core projects_, regardless of type.  It knows how to load their references & other properties.

Comment: There is also VisualStudioWorkspace that is a workspace hosted by visual studio that is used by plug-ins to VS.

Answer (score 3):

A Roslyn workspace is the common point where the model of the solution is accessed.

The difference between workspaces is mostly just how how the solution model is built, whether it is built up from reading a file, etc.

The MSBuildWorkspace builds a solution model for you from a msbuild solution or project file.

The AdhocWorkspace requires you to manually build up the solution via API calls adding projects and documents.

The DnxWorkspace builds up the solution model by reading those early dotnet core project.json files.

When Roslyn is used inside Visual Studio it is using a VisualStudioWorkspace that gets the solution model from the VS project system.